# Select entities with multiple keywords

Tags: doctrine, query-builder, symfony4

I'd like to select records where has at least one of searched keywords.
The keywords are stored in one field separated by comma like this :

```
+--------------------------+
| keywords                 |
+--------------------------+
|symfony,html,css,php,ajax | 
+--------------------------+
|symfony,php,linux,c++     | 
+--------------------------+
```

Assuming a user searches for these keywords : **symfony** and **html**

The query must returns this two lines above because keyword **symfony** exists in the two lines, but it returns just the first one witch keywords field contains this two keyword

```
    var_dump of $data['keywords']
    string(12) "symfony,html"
```

And this is the query

```
    if (!empty($data['keywords'])) {
        $keys = explode(',', $data['keywords']);
        foreach ($keys as $key)
        {
            $qb->andWhere('j.keywords like :keyword');
            $qb->setParameter("keyword", '%'.$key.'%');
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

**Solved**

```
        if (!empty($data['keywords'])) {
        $keywords = explode(',', $data['keywords']);
        $array = "";
        foreach (array_slice($keywords, 1) as $key => $value) {
            $array .= ' or j.keywords like :k' . $key;
            $qb->setParameter('k' . $key, '%' . $value . '%');
        }
        $qb->andWhere('j.keywords like :keyword ' . $array);
        $qb->setParameter("keyword", '%' . $keywords[0] . '%');
    }
```

and this is how the query is in the log

```
AND (j0_.keywords LIKE ? OR j0_.keywords LIKE ? OR j0_.keywords LIKE ? OR j0_.keywords LIKE ?) [2,"%symfony%","%html%","%test non existent keyword%"] []
```